# WordPress Get info from cmd/another place

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, node.js, wordpress

is it possible to host code on online place, running and send results to WordPress, so can read and use as well on Wordpress?
Thanks

Comment: WordPress/php can accept http requests, so why not? But this is too broad/vague to be a useful question on stackoverflow. See [ask].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. You can create an API project with API functions and Wordpress can send requests remotely to the API you are to create.